# List of all Android devices with characteristics

Tags: android, list, device

Currently I am investigating which Android devices I would like to support with my next Android app. I would love to have list that includes all Android devices with their characteristics.

Google provides this:
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Wikipedia provides some information but it is not structured:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

I would love to see a list with per device:

- Android OS
- Screen Density
- Screen Resolution
- Hardware specs
- Marketshare (sold)
- Marketshare (currently active)

And it should be possible to filter through the fields and see if you exclude some screen densities or resolution types how much marketshare there is still left.

I find it strange Google is not providing such a list as it would help Android developers a lot in determining priorities.

Anybody knows some resources which provide this information?

Comment: You support particular platform versions, not certain devices, so such list would be usually of no use (+ outdated)

Comment: When setting priorities a developer will not only need to determine which platforms to support but also screen densities and resolutions.

Comment: Rubbish. Unless you require specific device's feature you shall just care platform (API version). Other things are mostly kind of optional (nothing to bother) as long as your app is written right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Google does have this data, but they don't share it for some reason. Here's proof, if you open your developer console in Google Play, open your application and navigate to "APK" tab, it will give you the number of "Supported devices", like here: [http://www.mojandroid.sk/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Google-Play-Developer-Console-APK-súbory.png](http://www.mojandroid.sk/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Google-Play-Developer-Console-APK-s%C3%BAbory.png) This number will vary depending on what features you declared in your app's AndroidManifest.xml. In the old developer console there is an actual link, clicking on which opens a new window with a list of supported devices: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGsDG.jpg

Comment: Strange, maybe parties like Flurry or other analytics sites. If you would have traffic data from a popular website you might could get it from the http headers. You can also determine the amount of devices active.